# Альтернатива для socket.gethostbyname() с поддержкой асинхронности

Tags: python, сокет, асинхронность, asyncio, domain

Мне нужно получить ip сервера по домену.

Приведенный ниже способ работает хорошо, но он не асинхронный и сильно замедляет код.

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname('ya.ru')
```

Есть ли какие-то асинхронные решения для этой несложной задачи?

Comment: Если разобраться, как это работает, то выяснится, что задача на самом деле сложная, так как нужно обработать множество разных источников информации: DNS, WINS, файл hosts...

Comment: Но если вы вдруг уверены, что кроме DNS и файла hosts вам больше ничего не нужно, то можно просто взять какой-нибудь [aiodns](https://github.com/saghul/aiodns) наверное

Comment: А почему бы просто не засунуть это в экзекутор?

Comment: @eri интересно сравнить производительность с aiodns (накладные расходы и вся такая дребедень)

Comment: @andreymal в конкретной задаче надо сравнивать, а так - результат зависит от писателя теста)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Встроенный в asyncio ресолвер, скорее всего на базе тредов

```
In [2]: await asyncio.get_running_loop().getaddrinfo(
           'ya.ru',
           80,
           type=socket.SOCK_STREAM,
           flags=socket.AI_ADDRCONFIG,
           family=socket.AF_INET
        )
Out[2]: 
[(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>,
  <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>,
  6,
  '',
  ('87.250.250.242', 80))]
```

формат ответа массив `(family, type, proto, canonname, sockaddr)`

В объекте loop много чего есть, но gethostbyname нет.

А можно просто socket.gethostbyname запустить в executor .  aiodns предпочитают в проекте aiohttp, скорее всего выполнять днс напрямую менее накладно чем через ОС.